# Segmentation fault ao trocar system call the "int" para "syscall" em assembly x86 linux

Tags: linux, assembly

Quando eu mudo a system call de `int $0x80` para `syscall` ou `sysenter` neste código:

```
    mov $4, %rax
    mov $1, %rbx
    mov $String1, %rcx
    mov $16, %rdx
    int $0x80
```

o programa acaba em segmentation fault. No GDB mostra:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00000000f7ffdbe9 in ?? ()

Por que esta mudança está causando este impacto? Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **syscall** é para x86_64
- **sysenter** é para 32 bits
- **int 0x80** funciona para ambos

Isso é um resumo da mesma pergunta em:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806584/what-is-better-int-0x80-or-syscall